# Mark a product as consumed, Rails way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Today I'm trying to implement the following:

There are products in the site, and users.
If User is logged in ( if current_user), he can mark a product, like he is consuming that one. Later he can click on a button, and remove it from the consumed ones.

I'm struggling with this:

routes.rb

```
resources :users do
    member do
        get :product_add
        get :product_remove
    end
end
```

---

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def product_add
      if current_user
         @product = Product.find(params[:id])
         @user = current_user
         @user.product = []
         @user.product << @product.id
         redirect_to @product, notice: "succesful..."
      else
         redirect_to @product, notice: "error..."
      end
    end
end
```

---

```
class AddProductsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :product, :text
  end
end
```

There must be a Rails way to do this :) Please help me if you can.
Thanks!

Comment: saving your objects could help. btw `get` doesn't represent an action which changes the state of an object

Comment: what is the relationship between `user` and `product`, if any?

Comment: tehre is no relationship, but now i will try Zippies answer

Comment: only defining won't work.. you need to create migration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create three tables: `User`, `Product` and `ConsumedProducts`.
The `product` table and the `user` table have a many-to-many relationship.
The intermediate table would be `ConsumedProducts` where you would store the id of the user and the id of the product.

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :consumed_products;
   has_many :products, :through => :consumed_products
end

Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :consumed_products;
   has_many :users, :through => :consumed_products
end

Class ConsumedProducts < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :product
end
```

Each time a users clicks that he consumed a product, you would fill in the intermediate table with a user_id and a product_id. Each time he unchecks the product, you would delete that record.

**Also an alternative would be to use a has_and_belongs_to_many**, see the documentation for the difference (use this second one if your intermediate table has no extra attributes, which is your case, just be careful when your naming the extra table).

If you really want to implemented like that, you could something like you implemented, but with changed HTTP Methods:

```
resources :users do
    member do
        post :product_add
        delete :product_remove
    end
end
```

You can check this literature for more assistance: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Comment: last one Class ConsumedProducts?

Comment: yeah sorry, copy paste mistake :)

Comment: check the `has_and_belongs_to_many` reference in my answer and see the documentation for a bigger perspective of that association.

Answer (score 1):

Creating `many-to-many` relation:

```
class CreateUsersProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users_products, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :product_id
    end
  end
end

Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :products    
end

Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

def product_add
  if current_user
     @product = Product.find(params[:id])
     @user = current_user
     @user.products << @product.id
     redirect_to @product, notice: "succesful..."
  else
     redirect_to @product, notice: "error..."
  end
end
```

`has_many with :through` is used when you have `common attributes` for tables.

Comment: Are you trying to do a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship?

Comment: Well to be honest i don't really know whats the difference

Comment: oh, i wrote the difference in my answer, this question was directed to codeit :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Rails' [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). It enables you to easily create routes inside other routes. For example:

```
resources :users do
  resources :products
end

POST users/12/products/449    products#create
PUT  users/12/products/449    products#update
...
```

Then, in your ProductsController, you'll have access to a `param[:user_id]` as well as a `param[:product_id]`. Though you'll probably want to create a new table for Products as well as a mapping table between Products and Users (maybe UserProducts?).

Take a look at the [Rails association basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to learn more about linking tables together.